# How do I do multiple conversions when reading a file using np.genfromtxt?

Tags: python, numpy

So I am trying to import a .csv file into my python document using numpy.genfromtxt, this data looks something like this:

```
('column a', 'column b', 'column c', 'column d')
('238U', '100 %', '4.468e9 a', '234Th')
 ('234Th', '100 %', '24.10 d', '234mPa')
 ('"234mPa', '0.16 %', '1.159 m', '234Pa')
 ('"234mPa', '99.84 %', '1.159 m', '234U')
 ('234Pa', '100 %', '6.70 h', '234U')
 ('234U', '100 %', '2.455e5 a', '230Th')
```

The data in the 3rd column is the issue, they are half lifes (in years 'a', days 'd', months 'm' and so on...) which I have to convert into float type and so that they are in years (which means that for each letter they have to be dealt with differently). So far, I have tried using the converters argument to do this, such as:

```
convertfunc1 = lambda x: float(x.strip(b"a") or x.strip(b"m") or x.strip(b"h") or x.strip(b"d"))

  np.genfromtxt('data.csv',delimiter=',',skip_header=3, unpack=True,names=('parent','branch','half life','daughter'),usecols=(0,5,6,8),dtype=dtype1,converters={3:convertfunc1})
```

However, this only does the conversion for the first thing in the lambda function, (so in this case for the 'a's, such as:

```
('column a', 'column b', nan, 'column d')
('238U', '100 %', 4.468e9, '234Th')
 ('234Th', '100 %', nan, '234mPa')
 ('"234mPa', '0.16 %', nan, '234Pa')
 ('"234mPa', '99.84 %', nan, '234U')
 ('234Pa', '100 %', nan, '234U')
 ('234U', '100 %', 2.455e5, '230Th')
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: That doesn't look like a `csv` file.  When I answer questions like this I like to have a csv image that I can copy-n-paste to file ot multiline text string.  Omit the `unpack` for now; it confuses things.  What do you get without converters?

Comment: Without converters I get something like the data example at the top.